# How to prevent scaling due to DPI change?

Tags: excel, windows, vba, powerpoint

I'm using `Shapes.AddOLEObject` Powerpoint functionality in the Powerpoint VBA macros to get and display an Excel chart file (extension : `.xls`) onto a powerpoint slide when a [Display Chart] button is clicked.

```
Set shapeOnPPT = 
ActivePresentation.Slides.FindBySlideID(mySlideID).Shapes.AddOLEObject(Left:=100,_
Top:=100, Width:=500, Height:=400, FileName:="c:\ThisDoc\testing.xls", Link:=msoTrue)
```

**Problem**

After I change the DPI / resolution of my computer's display and click the [Display Chart] button, the new chart would either shrink / expand as shown below

[image]

**Workaround**

I would have to sign-out and sign-in again to 'refresh' the scaling to 100% for Excel charts.

**Question**

How do I address this problem? I don't want to have to sign-out/sign-in everytime the pc's resolution/DPI is changed.

Comment: Oddly programmers think that a screenshot is always good enough to show a scaling problem in their code.  It is not.  Whatever you do in your program to set the size of the graph, you'll have to make it 150% bigger.

Comment: Is the size affected only at the time you insert the chart or, having inserted the chart at one dpi setting, does the size of the chart change when you open the presentation again under a different dpi setting (or upon changing the dpi setting w/o closing/reopening the presentation)?  If the latter, I'd call it a bug in PPT.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg The size is affected everytime I call the `shapes.addOLEObject` function after I have changed the DPI setting.

Comment: In other words, once you've added the object, its size is fixed even after changing the DPI setting?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg correct. The size changes only after the `shapes.addOLEObject` is called.

Comment: Which version of PPT is this? I know that PPT in Office 365 has had some problems with DPI scaling in different ways and I think that there may been an update or two that partially addressed some of the problems. I'd make sure you're as updated as possible. Meanwhile, I'll see if I can get this thread in front of some folks at MS.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Microsoft PowerPoint 2013 (15.0.4903.1000) MSO (15.0.4911.1000) 32-bit Part of MS Office Professional Plus 2013. The OS being used is Win 10 Pro 64-bit. Also, laptop A that is generating the Excel chart is in reso 1920x1080 while laptop B that is opening the PPT to call the chart is in reso 1366x768 or lower.

Comment: Thanks.  I've passed the thread URL along to an acquaintance at MS.

Comment: @Mark After changing the Windows DPI, try logging out and back in again before inserting any objects.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg yes, it did solve my problem as stated in the question's workaround section above but I'm looking for solutions so that I don't have to logout and login again everytime I change the DPI/resolution.

Comment: Understood, but that's the only suggestion I got back from my contact at MS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GetSystemMetrics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) from the User32 library to get the current screen resolution, it's then just a question of applying a multiplier to your chart size based on the original screen resolution you designed the file with. Change sWOrig and sHOrig in the code below to the correct resolution.

```
Declare Function GetSystemMetrics32 Lib "User32" _
Alias "GetSystemMetrics" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Sub SizeChart()

Dim sW As Long, sH As Long
Dim sWOrig As Long, sHOrig As Long
Dim cW As Double, cH As Double
Dim wMulti As Double, hMulti As Double

sWOrig = 1920
sHOrig = 1080

sW = GetSystemMetrics32(0) ' screen resolution width in points
sH = GetSystemMetrics32(1) ' screen resolution height in points

wMulti = sW / sWOrig
hMulti = sH / sHOrig

cW = 500 * wMulti
sH = 400 * hMulti

Set test = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
test.Shapes.AddOLEObject Left:=100, Top:=100, _
Width:=cW, Height:=sH, _
FileName:="c:\ThisDoc\testing.xls"

End Sub
```

Comment: This is one of the few good reasons to call the chronically mis-used CreateGraphics().  Use its HorizontalResolution property to get the multiplier (divide by 96).